# How to fix java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

Tags: java, android, multithreading, kotlin, task

I saw some crash reports on Google Play Android vitals coming from this code:

```
val currentUser = auth.currentUser

            if (currentUser != null) {
                sessionToken = Tasks.await(currentUser.getIdToken(true)).token
                newRequest = request
                        .newBuilder()
                        .header(AUTHORIZATION, "$BEARER $sessionToken")
                        .build()
            } else {
                newRequest = request
                        .newBuilder()
                        .build()
            }
```

the line with the issue is this: **sessionToken = Tasks.await(currentUser.getIdToken(true)).token**

auth is FirebaseUser object. The code is in an interceptor and it adds the authorization token for the requests that need it.

I am not sure how to fix this. I am thinking of wrap all the code with

```
syncronized(this) {
       //here goes the code
}
```

but I am not sure if this will fix my problem.

Full stacktrace:

```
    java.lang.Error: 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
      at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
      at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb (Unknown Source:61)
      at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await (Unknown Source:23)
      at com.cofedistrict.data.remote.interceptors.TokenHeaderInterceptor.intercept (TokenHeaderInterceptor.kt:37)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
      at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept (HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
      at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
      at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain (RealCall.java:200)
      at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute (RealCall.java:147)
      at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run (NamedRunnable.java:32)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
 Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.
      at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.zza
      at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzfa.zza
      at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzet.zza
      at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzev.zza
      at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzed.zza
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact
      at android.os.Binder.execTransact (Binder.java:739)
```

Comment: Be sure to follow the exception chain to root cause: `com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException:`

Comment: i thought that user doesn't exist in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
val currentUser = auth.currentUser
```

to

```
val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
```

then check

```
if (currentUser != null) {
     //your code here
}
```

if my solution is not solve your issue then check it out that 
it said

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: The user's credential is no longer valid
```

so use a valid login credential.